# Google chrome and asp button click event issue

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, mouseclick-event

I'm working on an ASP.NET app
I have an asp button on my app with an associated server side click event

Now, this click event is not being fired with Google chrome (works fine on IE).
Chrome version is 5.0.375.55.

Any idea?
tks